# I want No select option using javascript or jquery

Tags: selectlist

I want By javascript or jquery   option value 0.0 Selected . Currently option value 2 is selected.

```
<select name="product_id" id="product_id" class="list_menu">
    <option value="0.0">Select</option>
    <option value="1">P1</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">P2</option>
    <option value="3">P3</option>
    <option value="4">P4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Also, as many would point out, jQuery *is* Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Plain javascript:

```
document.getElementById("product_id").selectedIndex = 0;
```

jQuery:

```
$("#product_id").val('')
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your "nothing" option is the first one:

`$('#product_id').val("0.0");`

EDIT: This is a jQuery reliant answer

Comment: Use quotes around the 0.0: $('#product_id').val('0.0');

Answer (score 0):

Plain JS for your exact select menu

```
document.getElementById('product_id').value = '0.0';
```